# What components should I use for a bicycle generator?

Tags: components, generator

I know next to nothing about electronics, ergo any help is gratefully received.

I'm trying to build the bicycle generator in [this Instructables guide](https://www.instructables.com/How-To-Build-A-Bicycle-Generator/), but there is no specification. I have so far found a 24V 280W scooter motor that could work, but:

1. What model of diode should I connect to it and the battery?
2. What kind of battery would be best?
3. What specification of inverter would I need for small applicances eg. 2kW fan heater, kettle, phone charger? (i.e. pure sine wave/modified sine wave etc.)

Comment: You are overestimating how much power a human can produce. An elite bicyclist can produce about 400 W of power for long periods of time. An average person probably 100-200 W. The generator won't be 100% efficient, so you will get less, maybe 75%. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_power

Comment: You must be built like the Hulk if you can generate 2kW of power for any length of time. Personally, I find 100W is hard to sustain for very long.

Comment: 2kW = 3HP. Three. Horses.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I was about to say, built like a pair of clydesdales. No one can expect to power 2 kW for any meaningful length of time. And I completely agree about the 100 W. Our local museum (OMSI) had a 100 W light bulb hooked up to a floor-stand bicycle. Anyone could jump up and give it a whirl. I was 19 and in good shape (not muscle-bound) and found it hard to keep well-lit for any meaningful duration. I think many people (most) have a very distorted idea of just how much power all of us routinely use.

Comment: A double-A (AA) alkaline battery, memory serving, has about 10 kJ of usable energy. Roughly 1000 of those AA batteries would be enough energy to shoot a Prius car a kilometer up into the air! And we burn through these things like they were paper. Just 50 RC Lipo's could do the same.

Comment: Folks, there's a **battery** in the system.  You don't have to provide a couple of kilowatts from pedaling.  You can store the energy in the battery at a low rate (100W) and use it at a high rate (2KW) from the battery.

Comment: A *gel* battery is similar to a lead-acid car battery, but is usually smaller and safer. The battery in the video is probably a gel battery.

Answer (score 1):

> I have so far found a 24V 280W scooter motor that could work

The important thing is to have the motor rotate at a suitable RPM so it makes enough voltage. If it turns too slow, you won't get any usable output. So you'll need to investigate about the motor's rpm rating when powered by, say, 12V, and possibly build some gearing, perhaps using belts. You could use a small wheel pushed against the bike's rear wheel, but that creates a lot of losses due to friction. I'd recommend using a used electric bicycle wheel motor, because that fits nicely in a bicycle wheel, it's got the proper rpm, and it's most convenient.

> What model of diode should I connect to it and the battery?

Schottky diode has lower voltage drop, so that would be best.

> What kind of battery would be best?

If you don't know what you're doing, don't use lithium. Maybe lead-acid.

> What specification of inverter would I need for small applicances eg. 2kW fan heater, kettle, phone charger? (i.e. pure sine wave/modified sine wave etc.)

An amateur cyclist can generate 100-200W for a few hours. Someone who doesn't exercise will do it for maybe a few minutes.

In other words, if you use a 12V battery, a car USB charger will be nice for your phone, there's no need to go from 12V to mains voltage back to 5V. Likewise for laptops.

As for the kettle and the 2kW fan heater, forget about it, you'd need 10-20 cyclists. Although, if you just want to heat the room with human power, you don't need anything fancy, just a stationary bike. The built-in brake converts the cyclist's energy output into heat without the extra cost of going through electricity, and since the human metabolism is only about 25% efficient, the cyclist will make 3x as much heat as the bike anyway. This will be cheaper than burning fuel only if food calories are cheaper than fuel calories, which is not a given.

Note it is not possible for anyone to produce 200W on a stationary bike (or do any kind of high-power exercise) for any length of time **indoors** without a fan to cool them. Without wind, they will simply overheat. So if you do build this, you will most likely use the generator to power a fan. In this case, for a mains powered fan, you need a pure sine wave inverter.

Comment: OK I have not been clear here -  I'm not suggesting that I can generate 2kw of power in a cycle - what i was intending was to charge up a battery over various hours of cycling and then use the battery to power the fan for however short a time. Am I wrong in thinking that this might be feasible?

Comment: Yes, that's doable, but it's not really reasonable. It will work fine to charge a laptop or a phone though.